# python regular expression irregular data

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to build a regular expression for my problem as follow:

I want to delete the content of "on node" and the rest of it till I reach the end, if the word after it is at the end of the sentence

e.g.

> PAA-NID30054-30102V2001P7 PAA_PL_ALERT is cleared on node
>   site-532332/6736356.

and

> PAC-NID43453-435346547 PAA_PL_ALERT is cleared on node siteground.

I have use the following regular expression for it:

```
on node.*
```

however, some of the entries have the "on node" in the middle of the sentence and I do not want to delete the rest of the sentence (i want to save the connection unavailable content)

e.g.

> VNOC-IPX DRA Alarm on node re-dsad-a - DEASWQ01_01 - Connection
>   Unavailable.

Thought of using:

```
on node.*-
```

However, it will not clear the word after "on node" for the first example.

Do you advice in using the start and end functions to decide if the matched was at the end of the string or not? i.e. create an if clause and check if the match is at the end use ., otherwise use -

Comment: Would you consider not using a regular expression?

Comment: I suggest using `str.split()` then. You can then apply various logic afterwards to the components. It's simple, reads and codes better, and fits this scenario a little better than regex IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the end of line marker in your regular expression. Maybe try this:

```
on node [^\s]*$
         |   ||__ End of line
         |   |___ Any amount
         |_______ Not a space character (space, tab, newline)
```

Comment: Make sure you're getting the space after `on node`. Unless Python's regex is different somehow it should work, but I can't test it right now. Maybe `[^\s]` doesn't work in Python? You can use `\S` to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to delete the content of "on node" and the rest of it till I reach the end, if the word after it is at the end of the sentence

It sounds like you want to remove `"on node"` and the next work after.

Try the following:

```
r'on node \S+'
```

Of course, it will have problems with

```
VNOC-IPX DRA Alarm on node re-dsad-a - DEASWQ01_01 - Connection Unavailable.
```

Since this is multiple words after the "on node". In this case your rules are too arbitrary of what you want to remove and want you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

If you were open to other ways (not using a regex) then a possible naive solution could use `str.split()`.

Generally speaking it would look something like this;

```
parts = line.split("on node")  # you now have some parts to look at
# if 'on node' was found this will be > 1
if len(parts) > 1:
  # additional logic to assess the second part of the string
  if parts[1].lower().find("connection unavailable") >= 0:
    # do something
  # do something more
```

Comment: ``if parts[1].lower()`` doesn't allow finding "Connection Unavailable" :)

Comment: @YannisP. - Thanks. It should be "connection unavailable" and I've changed that now. This is for a case insensitive match. the actual `find() >= 0` should be correct and the rest of the details are all up to the implementer.